# Replace the string pattern in file using python regex

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have following string pattern in a file I want to replace it with another string

```
import re
stringPatterenInFile = """ <div id="A4">

<br/>

<div style="padding: 2%;text-align: left;">

<p ><span style="color: #403052;"> <span style="font-size: large;"><strong>COMMERCIALS </strong></span></span><span style="color: #403052;"><span style="font-size: large;">AND TERMS OF ENGAGEMENT:<br /></span></span></p>
<p  align="justify">&nbsp;</p>



<div id="dynamicTable1">

<table class="dynamicTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Price</th> 
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Quote</th>
    <th>Tax</th>
    <th>Total</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Earthing Cabling</td>
    <td>100</td>   
    <td>345</td>
    <td>34500</td>
    <td>5175</td>
    <td>39675</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Earthing Cabling</td>
    <td>100</td>   
    <td>345</td>
    <td>34500</td>
    <td>5175</td>
    <td>39675</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Earthing Cabling</td>
    <td>100</td>   
    <td>345</td>
    <td>34500</td>
    <td>5175</td>
    <td>39675</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Earthing Cabling</td>
    <td>100</td>   
    <td>345</td>
    <td>34500</td>
    <td>5175</td>
    <td>39675</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Earthing Cabling</td>
    <td>100</td>   
    <td>345</td>
    <td>34500</td>
    <td>5175</td>
    <td>39675</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Earthing Cabling</td>
    <td>100</td>   
    <td>345</td>
    <td>34500</td>
    <td>5175</td>
    <td>39675</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Earthing Cabling</td>
    <td>100</td>   
    <td>345</td>
    <td>34500</td>
    <td>5175</td>
    <td>39675</td>

  <tr>
    <td>Earthing Cabling</td>
    <td>100</td>   
    <td>345</td>
    <td>34500</td>
    <td>5175</td>
    <td>39675</td>

  </tr>
</table>
</div>

</div>
</div>

<br/>"""
```

Want to replace with:-

```
<div id='dynamicTable1'><table class='dynamicTable'><tr><th>Description</th><th>Price</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Quote</th><th>Tax</th><th>Total</<tr><td>Earthing Cabling</td><td>100</td><td>345</td><td>34500</td><td>5175</td><td>39675</td></tr></table></div>
```

I am Using regex:-

```
a = re.match(r"^<div id='dynamicTable1'><table class='dynamicTable'>(.*?)</table></div></div></div>$", text)
```

But It's not working it's printing `None`

Comment: You want to remove all the newlines? or the replaced string has more differences?

Comment: I want to replace string as it is

Answer (score 0):

I got solution as follows:

```
with open('InputFileName') as inf:
            txt = inf.read()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(txt)

for i in rows:
    tr_tag = soup.new_tag("tr")

    for n in i.values():
        new_tag = soup.new_tag("td")
        new_tag.string = n
        tr_tag.append(new_tag)  

    soup.find("table", {"class": "dynamicTable"}).append(tr_tag)    


# save the file again
with open('ModifiedFileName', "w") as outf:
    outf.write(str(soup))
```